# Is this textbook wrong? Specialising some member functions but not others

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-specialization

I'm reading Vandevoorde and Josuttis's "C++ Templates The Complete Guide" (which seems pretty good, by the way). This claim (section 3.3) seems to be wrong [and is not in the published errata](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/errata1_5.html):

> If you specialise a class template, you must also specialise all member functions. Although it is possible to specialise a single member function, once you have done so, you can no longer specialise the whole class.

Yet the following compiles on gcc
template

```
<typename T>
struct C {
    T foo ();
    T bar ();
};

template <>
struct C<int> {
    int foo ();
    int bar () {return 4;}
};

template <typename T>
T C<T> :: foo () {return 0;}

template <typename T>
T C<T> :: bar () {return 1;}

int C<int> :: foo () {return 2;}

template <>
float C<float> :: bar () {return 3;}

#include <cassert>

int main () {
    C<int> i;
    C<float> f;
    assert (2 == i .foo ());
    assert (0 == f .foo ());
    assert (4 == i .bar ());
    assert (3 == f .bar ());
}
```

I have specialised `C<int>::foo` and `C<float>::bar` so is the textbook wrong, is gcc going beyond the standard, or am I misunderstanding the whole situation?

Thanks.

Comment: You misinterpreted the rule. Once you specialized a member function you cannot specialize a class on the same type, not on all other types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this:

```
template <typename T> struct C
{
   T foo ()     { return 0;}
   T bar ()     { return 1;}
};

// partial specialization of foo on C<int>
template <>
int C<int> :: foo () {return 2;}

// partial specialization of bar on C<float>
template <>
float C<float> :: bar () {return 3;}

// will not compile, C<int> already partially specialized
template <>
struct C<int>
{
   int foo() {return 10;}
   int bar() {return 10;}
};
```

Comment: This is an ordinary redefinition error, nothing to do with templates. Is this why I'm confused? Simply because it got mentioned in the context of templates? Good grief...

Comment: In this context you can think of it like that yes.  If you remove the implementation of `foo()` in the specialization of `C<int>`, it will simply treat the partial specialization as the implementation of this function.

Answer (score 4):

No, the book isn't wrong. Your understanding is, I am afraid :)

In this case you have specialized ***only 1 member function*** - `foo` for `C<int>` and `bar` for `C<float>`

Now you can't explicitly specialize `C<int>` or `C<float>`. But you can specialize `C<char>`

Comment: Please see my updated question. I've now specialised one function (bar) for `C<float>` and given a full specialisation for `C<int>` -- doesn't ***this*** contradict the textbook?

Comment: No, your "partial specialization" of C<int>::foo() is simply actually the definition for the fully specialized version.  See my answer below for details.